# Xammp bitnami joomla ssl

Tags: ssl, joomla, bitnami

Hello I would like some pointers for enabling ssl on bitnami joomla that works with xampp I have read many tutorials nothing seems to work.I have tried to forse ssl from joomla adminstrator it says that the connection is not safe where might the problem be i see that the cert is not trusted i accepted it as trusted but still doesn't work .if someone knows the answer please share!

Comment: I fixed the problem but here is something that confuses me the cert that my site takes says that it does  not have the appropriate ip .The thing is this is apache's cert while bitnami joomla has another cert that probably works how can i configure this to accept joomla's cert?

Comment: I made a self signed certificate and put it at the apache folders but in chrome says that the cert is not trustworthy and does not display my site how can i fix this ?Its for my thesis and I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,

I have created a new auto-signed certificate using our guide at https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_create_a_SSL_certificate.3f and modified file `installdir/etc/extras/httpd-ssl.conf` to use the new certificate files and after that restarted Apache server with `sudo installdir/ctlscript.sh restart apache`. It worked for me. The lines I modified in `httpd-ssl.conf` are:

```
...
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/server.crt"
...
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/server.key"
...
```

Then, I browsed my server using HTTPS and it showed an error page with error code `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.

That means that the certificate is invalid because of the Certificate Authority is not a trusted one. It is completely normal because I have auto-signed the certificate. To skip this, click the "Advanced options" button and then click the link "Proceed to ...". You should see your website.

Also in the navigation bar you will see text "https" in red. If you click in the lock close to it, it will prompt a window with text:

```
The identity of this website has not been verified.
  • Server's certificate is not trusted.
Your connection to your_domain.com is encrypted with modern cryptography.
The connection uses TLS 1.2.
The connection is encrypted and authenticated using AES_128_GCM and uses ECDHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism.
```

Regards,

Gonzalo

Comment: thavks for the help !